# How to Type Screenplay in Flutter Textfield

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textinputfield

When the **next line** was the start alignment, the **central alignment** should come, and also the width of the paragraph should be reduced. Another solution required is end alignment on the next line in Textfield.
( like Final draft App or Celtx App).
ex:-

short...bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bb
bbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

```
                                    Uncle
                   BBBBBBBBBBBBBbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
                   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
                   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbb
                   (DIALOG)


                                                                                    CUT TO
                                                                                    (Transition)
```

```
class Popup extends StatefulWidget {
  const Popup({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Popup> createState() => _PopupState();
}

class _PopupState extends State<Popup> {
  final TextEditingController textEditor =
      TextEditingController(text: '\u200B');

  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  final List<String> opnTab = [
    '\u2029\u2028',
    '\u2029\u2028',
    '\u2029\u2028',
    '\u2029\u0028\u0029',
    '\u2029\u2028',
    '\u2029\u200B\u2029',
    '\u2029\u2028\u0009',
    '\u200B\u201c\u201d',
  ];
  late int preseIndex = 0;

  bool diolg = false;
  bool iconPressed = false;
  late String positionText;
  int enterCount = 0;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    textEditor.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: RawKeyboardListener(
                  focusNode: FocusNode(),
                  onKey: (event) {
                    if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter)) {
                      preseIndex++;
                      preseIndex < opnTab.length ? preseIndex : preseIndex = 0;
                      preseIndex == 4 ? diolg = true : false;
                      int cursorPos = textEditor.selection.base.offset;
                      final String preseIndexText = opnTab[preseIndex];
                      textEditor.text =
                          '${textEditor.text}$preseIndexText\u200B';
                      textEditor.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                        TextPosition(
                            offset: preseIndex == 3
                                ? opnTab[preseIndex].length + cursorPos - 1
                                : opnTab[preseIndex].length + cursorPos + 1),
                      );
                      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
                        _scrollController.jumpTo(
                            _scrollController.positions.first.maxScrollExtent);
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  child: TextField(
                    scrollController: _scrollController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
                    autofocus: true,
                    maxLines: null,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.yellow,
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      isDense: true,
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      wordSpacing: 5,
                    ),
                    controller: textEditor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Flutter Textfield in paragraph